# Iterating through an ArrayList twice when searching for Objects with specified properties

Tags: java, list

I am trying to iterate through a List, and create a Pair of 2 objects, that are both stored in `data`. Both objects will have a property `isSuspended`, one will have the property set to `true` and other one to `false`.

This is the code I am using.

```
Pair<Market, Market> marketPair;
        for (Market market : data) {
            if (!market.getIsSuspended() && !market.wasProcessed) {
                for (Market market2 : data) {
                    if (market2.getIsSuspended() && !market2.wasProcessed) {
                        marketPair = new Pair<>(market, market2);
                        market.setWasProcessed(true);
                        market2.setWasProcessed(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

However, this code is going to be slow. It is executed on batches with size of 5000. Total number of records is more than 10 millions, so I am searching for a way to make this faster. Do I really need 2 for loops?

Comment: From where are you fetching this data is that a db query or something else?

Comment: It's probably more efficient to handle this in SQL.

Comment: Also, it looks like you only return one pair, so it might be better to break both of your loops, so it doesn't continue after you found a pair.

Comment: Data comes from mongo. There are possibly more pairs than just one.

Comment: And it is how @Andreas said in his answer, there could be a rollover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the list once, filtering out `wasProcessed`. Add entry to one of two lists: `isSuspended` and `notSuspended`. Now pair up entries from each list.

```
List<Market> isSuspended = new ArrayList<>();
List<Market> notSuspended = new ArrayList<>();
for (Market market : data) {
    if (! market.wasProcessed) {
        if (market.getIsSuspended())
            isSuspended.add(market);
        else
            notSuspended.add(market);
    }
}
Iterator iter1 = notSuspended.iterator();
Iterator iter2 = isSuspended.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext() && iter2.hasNext()) {
    Market market1 = iter1.next();
    Market market2 = iter2.next();
    Pair<Market, Market> marketPair = new Pair<>(market1, market2);
    market1.setWasProcessed(true);
    market2.setWasProcessed(true);
    // use marketPair here
}
```

---

However, if this is a continual process, processed in batches of 5000, where there might be rollover entries from one of the lists, use a [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) instead.

```
Deque<Market> isSuspended = new ArrayDeque<>();
Deque<Market> notSuspended = new ArrayDeque<>();
for (;;) { // loop forever
    data = /*get next batch here*/;
    if (data.isEmpty())
        break;

    // Find unprocessed
    for (Market market : data) {
        if (! market.wasProcessed) {
            if (market.getIsSuspended())
                isSuspended.add(market);
            else
                notSuspended.add(market);
        }
    }

    // Pair up
    while (! notSuspended.isEmpty() && ! isSuspended.isEmpty()) {
        Market market1 = notSuspended.remove();
        Market market2 = isSuspended.remove();
        Pair<Market, Market> marketPair = new Pair<>(market1, market2);
        market1.setWasProcessed(true);
        market2.setWasProcessed(true);
        // use marketPair here
    }
}
```